# React useState update not updating immediately until I pass a random activator

Tags: reactjs, use-state

So I found out a really weird React useState behavior when testing and can't really explain why.

So below is my code. I am creating a React ListItem with Checkbox. Since user can select multiple checkbox so I feel it's best to store the active index using an array. And use array.includes function to check if that certain index is active or not. When I was doing it I find out the array useState is not update immediately so my checkbox check doesn't work. However I add a random activator like below and suddenly the array get updated in time and my code starts working. I hope my question is clear. Can someone explain why is this happening?

I did more testing and find out activator need to pass in the index variable. If I pass in some random value it will cause inconsistent behavior

```
 const [activeIndex, setactiveIndex] = useState([]);
 const [_, activator] = useState(-1);  //If I add this line of code the array gets updated in time

  const ModifyActiveIndex = (index) => {
    activator(index);
    if (!activeIndex.includes(index)) {
      const copy = activeIndex;
      copy.push(index);
      setactiveIndex(copy);
    } else {
  
      const filtercopy = activeIndex.filter((item) => {
        return item !== index;
      });
      setactiveIndex(filtercopy);
    }
  };

  const checkEntityactive = (index) => {
    return activeIndex.includes(index);
  };

  const ProductList = temp.map((element, index) => {
    return (
      <ListItem key={index}>
        <Checkbox
          checked={checkEntityactive(index)}
          onClick={() => ModifyActiveIndex(index)}
        />
      </ListItem>
    );
  });
```

Comment: `const copy = activeIndex;` does not create a copy, it's essentially just renaming `activeIndex` to `copy`, the array is still the same reference, so you're changing your state in place when you use `.push()`. You also don't need to create a `copy` variable when you perform your filter, as the filter method will create a new array for you

Comment: Yea that line of code I just add during testing. I can take it out. But that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I guess if you take it out then you're probably doing something like `activeIndex.push(index)`? If so, you're still modifying the state directly if you're doing that. You'd need to create a new array, and add your new index to that `setactiveIndex([...activeIndex, index])`

Comment: Yea still the only way my code will work is to add activator(index) line. All other changes can make code simpler but it doesn't solve the problem. I just want to know why is that line of code solve my problem

Comment: When the code is executed to `copy.push(index);`, the state has been changed, but the parameter of `setactiveIndex(copy)` is an array reference, so the component will not be re-rendered until `activator(index);`. `activator(index);` will be executed after `copy.push(index);` because setState is asynchronous inside event handlers. Actually, If you delete `setactiveIndex(copy);`. It still works.

Answer (score 1):

```
const copy = activeIndex;
copy.push(index);
setactiveIndex(copy);
```

`activeIndex` is an array, and you can't copy them in this way.

In the first line, you make a pointer called `copy` and its point to `activeIndex` place, so every change in copy(like push() in the second line) would directly change `activeIndex`, so you are changing the state, without calling setState in the second line. (It cause your app to be unpredictable)

you can change this 3 lines in this way:

```
setactiveIndex([...activeIndex, index]);
```

Comment: Ok thanks it did solve the problem but it didn't tell me why add the line activator(index) also works

Comment: Because by calling 'activator(index)' you are forcing the component to rerender by changing the index,  and without it, in if case, you are not updating the 'activeIndex' with 'setActiveIndex' so the component will never update as soon as it goes on the if state